# How can I stop a timer when I get out of my Activity?

Tags: android

I built a timer, and even when I go out from the activity, the Timer continues, how can I stop it when I leave the current activity?

Thread:

```
   t = new Thread() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
            try {
              while (!isInterrupted()) {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      try {

                        output = new teste().execute(getconversationid).get();
                        setMyInt(output);
                        Log.e("", output);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                  }
                });
              }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
          }
        };

        t.start();
```

Answer (score -1):

In onDestroy() or onStop() method stop the timer thread by calling

> t.kill();

On the other hand I would recommend using a simple cound down timer class instead of building one yourself. and then call objectname.cancle() in onDestroy or onStop() method.

```
public class pauseTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public pauseTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }



    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }
}
```

Comment: i received this The method kill() is undefined for the type 
  Thread